# what is the best way to save content to mongodb via google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, mongodb, google-chrome-extension

I want to save content of page in mongodb using google chrome extension. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of middleware which accepts REST Calls from your browsers extension.
This is the best approach i guess.

Comment: i thought about this way, how can i get an url to localhost to my rest api ?

Comment: What do you mean with that?
You need to setup some kind of server which allows you to address REST calls to Port 80 for example.

You can then send your requests to http://127.0.0.1